# Short and unique keys in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I want to write a URL shortener as a standalone CouchApp, but I'm wondering if it is possible.
Obviously, a core requirement for a URL shortener is to have short and unique keys.

What I want is to POST a long URL to CouchDB and get a shortened URL. I thought about using an update handler, but it would have to query the DB to check if the key is unique, which seems not to be possible.

Is there a way to generate short and unique keys with CouchDB? Or do I need a thin wrapper around CouchDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a thin wrapper, based on documents with the following structure:

```
{ _id : short_url , url : long_url }
```

Inserting of a new long URL could be done in a single step: have the wrapper generate a new `_id`, attempt a PUT, and try again with a new `_id` until it succeeds. This will guarantee that every short URL is only used once.

*I'm afraid this "generate, attempt, retry" approach is the only strategy that ensures uniqueness, and it's not available without a wrapper.*

If you wish the same long URL to reuse the same short URL, you can also add a view that `echo(doc.url,null)` and grab the `_id` for your URL if it does exist. This means that, unless several clients try to add the same long URL at the exact same time, only one short URL will be used for that long URL.

Comment: I found out that implementing the "generate, attempt, retry" strategy is possible with an external process, but it's not pretty. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/ExternalProcesses

Comment: You must also make sure that your document _ids are unique across nodes so that you can safely replicate! One method would be to add a unique prefix for each node. Though that is not infinitely scalable as you could only have n*64 nodes where n is the number of characters you allow for each node prefix (64 is the number of url safe characters you can use in your _ids). Also if you have a few million urls you may have to retry your PUT many times before you get a unique short id...